# Command to switch branches in GIT

Tags: git, svn

I had worked with SVN and it has an option to switch branches like, svn switch branch name. I am not sure whether git requires the same switching to work on another branch. I have 2 branches like 1.0 and 1.1. So far I have worked on 1.0, is git pull origin 1.1 and git push origin 1.1 enough? or should I switch the branch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Git command [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is used to change between branches. This is similar to `svn switch`.

Comment: @Slasengger: Great. I recommend the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/) book for Git basics, it's really good.

Comment: I will get one and start looking into it Greg:) Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
git checkout branch_name
```

will switch to the branch_name

if you want to create new branch then following command will be usefull

```
$git checkout -b branch_name
```